# Efficiently sort a delimited string of numbers and rearrange related delimited strings to match the sort

Tags: php, performance, sorting, delimiter

I've got three strings generated from a long process of combined queries and file reads, each related to the other.

---

**Example:**

```php
$versions = "1 2 5 4 10 6 8 7 3 9";
$weights = "50.2 60.5 35 10 15.98 60 50 60.1 70 75";
$ids = "512 318 112 326 155 191 977 961 943 441";
```

I would like to sort them in ascending order according to version number.

**Example result:**

```php
$versions = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";
$weights = "50.2 60.5 70 10 35 60 60.1 50 75 15.98";
$ids = "512 318 943 326 112 191 961 977 441 155";
```

---

My question is: is there a more efficient way of doing this than I am currently doing it?
Note that these strings can become big, largest I've seen so far is ~600 different versions

I do the following:

- explode strings
- copy arrays with version number as keys
- sort arrays by keys
- implode strings back

Here's the code and [a live example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/L2oFHk):

```php
$versions = "1 2 5 4 10 6 8 7 3 9";
$weights = "50.2 60.5 35 10 15.98 60 50 60.1 70 75";
$ids = "512 318 112 326 155 191 977 961 943 441";

$a_versions = explode(" ", $versions);
$a_weights = explode(" ", $weights);
$a_ids = explode(" ", $ids);

$s_versions = array();
$s_weights = array();
$s_ids = array();

//set keys to correspond to version number
foreach($a_versions as $key => $ver){
    $s_versions[$ver] = $a_versions[$key];
    $s_weights[$ver] = $a_weights[$key];
    $s_ids[$ver] = $a_ids[$key];
}

//sort according to keys
ksort($s_versions, SORT_NUMERIC);
ksort($s_weights, SORT_NUMERIC);
ksort($s_ids, SORT_NUMERIC);

//implode back
$versions = implode(" ", $s_versions); 
$weights = implode(" ", $s_weights); 
$ids = implode(" ", $s_ids); 

echo "
    <pre>
        $versions
        $weights
        $ids
    </pre>
";

/*==========
Results
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    50.2 60.5 70 10 35 60 60.1 50 75 15.98
    512 318 943 326 112 191 961 977 441 155
==========*/
```

---

Performance increase #1:

> Replacing the foreach loop with array_combine might give a little performance gain. – svens

Indeed it did, according to [a simple unit test](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IktTtR), it's about 11-15% faster.

Comment: Replacing the `foreach` loop with `array_combine` might give a little performance gain.

Comment: @svens Indeed it did, it increased the efficiency by about 12% (average from 100 executions)

Comment: @ShadowScripter are the versions (the values in `$versions`) unique? Or can there be multiple occurrences of the same version?

Comment: @Yoshi Good question, the `$versions` are unique, as well as the `$ids`.

Comment: @ShadowScripter But they will allways be integers (eg. 1 - n)?

Comment: @Yoshi Yes, the versions are incrementing integers starting from 1 and up. Some are generated in the database, some are generated when reading from files. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I could find:

```
$versions = array_flip(explode(' ', $versions));
$weights = explode(' ', $weights);
$ids = explode(' ', $ids);

ksort($versions, SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach ($versions as $version => $idx) {
  $result[0][] = $version;
  $result[1][] = $weights[$idx];
  $result[2][] = $ids[$idx];
}

return array(
  implode(' ', $result[0]),
  implode(' ', $result[1]),
  implode(' ', $result[2]),
);
```

See: 
http://codepad.viper-7.com/flcvnO
for a comparison of what I tested (including you initial code and the one with array_combine)

Comment: Very impressive, and simple! Didn't know `array_flip` existed, very cool. Also appreciate the test you provided. May I ask why you made your test layout that way?

Comment: @ShadowScripter It just seemed to be the simplest way to compare those methods. Also `array_multisort` tends to get slower on longer version-strings, so I tried to get better test-data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. This is the simplest example, with no keys:

```
$versions = "1 2 5 4 10 6 8 7 3 9";
$weights = "50.2 60.5 35 10 15.98 60 50 60.1 70 75";
$ids = "512 318 112 326 155 191 977 961 943 441";

$a_versions = explode(" ", $versions);
$a_weights = explode(" ", $weights);
$a_ids =  explode(" ", $ids);

$version_weight_id = array_map(null, $a_versions, $a_weights, $a_ids);

print_r($version_weight_id);
```

If you want something more keyed, you'll have to have a map function, like so:

```
function version_weight_id($v, $w, $id) {

    return array('version' => $v, 'weight' => $w, 'id' => $id);

}

$versions = "1 2 5 4 10 6 8 7 3 9";
$weights = "50.2 60.5 35 10 15.98 60 50 60.1 70 75";
$ids = "512 318 112 326 155 191 977 961 943 441";

$a_versions = explode(" ", $versions);
$a_weights = explode(" ", $weights);
$a_ids =  explode(" ", $ids);

$version_weight_id = array_map('version_weight_id', $a_versions, $a_weights, $a_ids);

array_multisort($version_weight_id, $a_versions);

print_r($version_weight_id);
```

#### Edit:

Here is another approach that doesn't require a map function:

```
$versions = "1 2 5 4 10 6 8 7 3 9";
$weights = "50.2 60.5 35 10 15.98 60 50 60.1 70 75";
$ids = "512 318 112 326 155 191 977 961 943 441";

$a_versions = explode(" ", $versions);
$a_weights = explode(" ", $weights);
$a_ids =  explode(" ", $ids);

$weights_ids = array_map(null, $a_weights, $a_ids);
$versions_weights_ids = array_combine($a_versions, $weights_ids);

print_r($versions_weights_ids);
```

The catch is that you have to know that the primary key is the version, the subarray 0 key is the weight, and the subarray 1 key is the id.

To print out your result you would use:

```
foreach($versions_weights_ids as $version => $weight_id) {
echo "
    <pre>
        $version
        {$weight_id[0]}
        {$weight_id[1]}
    </pre> ";
}
```

If you are looking for an ajax solution, I would consider JSON, and go with something more like:

```
$versions = "1 2 5 4 10 6 8 7 3 9";
$weights = "50.2 60.5 35 10 15.98 60 50 60.1 70 75";
$ids = "512 318 112 326 155 191 977 961 943 441";

$a_versions = explode(" ", $versions);
$a_weights = explode(" ", $weights);
$a_ids =  explode(" ", $ids);

$weights_ids = array_map(null, $a_weights, $a_ids);
$versions_weights_ids = array_combine($a_versions, $weights_ids);

echo json_encode($versions_weights_ids);
```

This way, you can use the framework's each method or target a specific version (or versions) to output.

Comment: The arrays needs to be imploded back to the three strings after sorting, how would you do that efficiently using your method? Other than that, its a nice solution!

Comment: @ShadowScripter - If you already have them as strings, why do you need to implode them back?

Comment: The point of this whole thing was to sort the strings according to the version numbers. This is later used in an AJAX fetch where I do another split/explode on the javascript side, but I want the versions/weights/ids sorted before then. I thought it was clearly demonstrated in my post, section "Example" and "Example result".

Comment: Your edit did allowed me to adjust the output to what I needed. When doing [a simple unit test](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Xtqkk0), it shows that your method is equal to or slightly faster than the original. While svens' is the fastest.